# Yield operator with IEnumerable<Lazy<T,T>>

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield

Why both methods fails in compile time?

> Error 1   The body of
>   'TestMethod(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>)'
>   cannot be an iterator block because
>   'Core.Interfaces.IBusinessPluginMetadata' is not an iterator interface
>   type ...

```cs
    IBusinessPluginMetadata TestMethod(IEnumerable<Lazy<IBusinessPlugin, IBusinessPluginMetadata>> plugins)
    {
        foreach (Lazy<IBusinessPlugin, IBusinessPluginMetadata> plugin in plugins)
        {
            yield return (IBusinessPluginMetadata)plugin.Metadata; 
        }
    }

    IBusinessPluginMetadata TestMethod(IEnumerable<Lazy<IBusinessPlugin, IBusinessPluginMetadata>> plugins)
    {
            yield return plugins.Select(a => a.Metadata);
    }
```

```
<!-- language: c# -->
public virtual ObservableCollection<IBusinessPluginMetadata> PluginsMetadata { get { } }
<!-->
```

I would like to fill my ObservableCollection property using get accessor with one of those methods.

Comment: You can only use `yield` if you return `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerator<T>`, or `IEnumerator`.  From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

Comment: If `Enumerable.Select` returns an iterator, how do you expect the method to return `IBusinessPluginMetadata`?

Comment: Also there shouldn't be a need to cast `Metadata` as it's already of type `IBusinessPluginMetadata`.

Answer (score 0):

After `yield return` you should specify a single element and call that in the method repeatedly to have it return multiple elements. The method should return `IEnumerable<IBusinessPluginMetadata>`.

In your first case change the return type to `IEnumerable<IBusinessPluginMetadata>` and you're good to go.

In your second case `Select` already returns a iterator, just return that.